# Read-only file system error when loading docker image

Tags: docker

I have a RedHat 7 instance running Docker 1.6, and am experiencing a problem when loading a custom docker image. The image was created on a Ubuntu 14.04 environment with Docker 1.5. The image has successfully loaded on the RedHat 7 instance in the past, but after having reinstalled docker (along with removing the containers and images) & updated the software on the server, I get the following error when loading in the image tar file:

```
FATA[0147] Error response from daemon: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: 
stderr: write /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/oc4j/j2ee/home/applications/ascontrol.ear: read-only file system
```

The image has an oracle database installed, and after running the load many times, the system seems to error on different files in the oracle install directory.

I don't really have any guesses as to why this error is occurring, or why this issue did not occur originally.

It's also worth noting that I attempted to load this image on an RH 6 environment as well, and have noticed the same behavior.